# $R^{\dim X-\dim Y}f_{\ast}\omega_X \simeq \omega_Y$ in positive characteristic?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

In Proposition 7.6 of his paper "Higher Direct Images of Dualizing Sheaves", Kollár shows that if $X,Y$ are smooth complex projective varieties and $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is a proper surjective morphism with connected fibers, then there is an isomorphism $R^df_{\ast}\omega_X \simeq \omega_Y$, where $d=\dim X-\dim Y$.

I was wondering whether this is true in positive characteristic. By Grothendieck duality one has $$Rf_{\ast}\mathcal{O}_X \simeq Rf_{\ast}R\mathcal{H}om(\omega_X^{\bullet},\omega_X^{\bullet}) \simeq R\mathcal{H}om(Rf_{\ast}\omega_X^{\bullet}, \omega_Y^{\bullet})[-d]$$ so taking 0-th cohomology we get $$f_{\ast}\mathcal{O}_X \simeq \mathcal{E}xt^{-d}(Rf_{\ast}\omega_X^{\bullet}, \omega_Y^{\bullet})$$

From the spectral sequence $$\mathcal{E}xt^p(\mathcal{H}^{-q}(\mathcal{F}^{\bullet}), \mathcal{G}^{\bullet}) \Longrightarrow \mathcal{E}xt^{p+q}(\mathcal{F}^{\bullet},\mathcal{G}^{\bullet})$$ it follows that the RHS is isomorphic to $\mathcal{H}om(R^df_{\ast}\omega_X,\omega_Y)$ and the LHS is just $\mathcal{O}_Y$ by the connected fibers assumption so we have $$\mathcal{O}_Y \simeq \mathcal{H}om(R^df_{\ast}\omega_X,\omega_Y)$$

Finally since $R^df_{\ast}\omega_X$ is locally free we conclude that $R^df_{\ast}\omega_X \simeq \omega_Y$.

Comment: Where did you get the $[-d]$ in the first displayed equation? Or alternatively you should drop the $^\bullet$ from the dualizing complexes. If you do that, then you end up with either $\mathscr Ext^0$ or $^{-d}$, but without the $^\bullet$'s. (cont'd)

Comment: Isn't such vanishing the result of Chatzistamatiou and Rülling in "Higher direct images of the structure sheaf
in positive characteristic", ANT 2011?

Comment: @MatthieuRomagny: No. They handle the case when $d=0$ and even pose this as an open problem.

Comment: ... and the case of $d=0$ of this question is straightforward.

Comment: The case of $d = 0$ is even known in mixed characteristic and goes back at least to Lipman in his work in the 70s.  I do have something to say about the question though which is probably too big to fit in a comment.

Answer (score 6):

So a paper of Blickle, myself and Tucker handles some questions really closely related to this, see [the arXiv version here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1107.3807.pdf)

Ok, throw away the connected fibers hypothesis, I'm going to assume my base field is $F$-finite (although we can also work with integral $F$-finite separated schemes instead of varieties).

Suppose that $f : X \to Y$ is a proper surjective morphism of varieties in characteristic $p > 0$.  Then we have a map $R^d \pi_* \omega_X \to \omega_Y$.  This map is never zero (see Prop 2.13 in the aforementioned paper).

The nice thing is that the image of this morphism in $\omega_Y$ always contains the *parameter test submodule* $\tau(\omega_Y) \subseteq \omega_Y$ (see Prop 2.21 and Definition 2.33).  For smooth varieties, $\tau(\omega_Y) = \omega_Y$ (and even for varieties with *mild* singularities).  It's worth remarking that this is in some sense optimal:  For non-smooth varieties, we also show that there always exists some $X \to Y$ such that $\tau(\omega_Y)$ is the image of $R^d \pi_* \omega_X \to \omega_Y$.

Anyway, the upshot of the above discussion is that if $Y$ is smooth, then $R^d \pi_* \omega_X \to \omega_Y$ is surjective.  Obviously without the connected fibers hypothesis, it can't be injective.

**EDIT:** Ok, so then we need the injectivity under the hypothesis of connected fibers (or maybe also $X$ smooth).  In an earlier version of this ansewr I was incorrectly speculating that maybe we could use something like the argument in the question to help here.  As  Sándor points out, that won't work...

Comment: Karl, I meant to post an answer with essentially the same conclusion (without appealing to your test submodule). I don't see how that spectral sequence would help with the injectivity. That is equivalent to saying that $R^d\pi_*\omega_X$ is torsion-free (which is also shown by Kollár in char=0). The OP claims that it is locally free... I don't see why.

Comment: BTW, you exchanged $X$ and $Y$ everywhere where there is an $R^d\pi_*$...

Comment: Hi Sándor, thanks, and I also fixed the $X$ to $Y$ stuff.